# NestJS Handle MongoError

Tags: node.js, mongoose, nestjs

I have a NestJS application (version 7) that it's using `mongoose`. The packages that are installed are `@nestjs/mongoose` and `mongoose`.

I want to create an ExceptionFilter that will catch `mongoose` errors.

```
 @Post('/register')
 @HttpCode(201)
 @UseFilters(MongoExceptionFilter)
 @UsePipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }))
 async register(){}
```

And the MongoExceptionFilter

```
@Catch(MongoError)
export class MongoExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
......
}
```

The problem is that I can't import MongoError from `mongodb`, because it will not work, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/2664#issuecomment-525687266).

The question is, from where should I import this `MongoError` so that NestJS will catch the errors that mongoose will throw. From what I see neither `mongoose` nor `@nestjs/mongoose` are exposing this object.

UPDATE

https://github.com/GeoPablo/nest-demo-mongo - here is a GitHub repo

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Answer (score -1):

**Import Error from mongoose package.**

`import { Error } from 'mongoose';`

**From the official Mongoose Docs :**

1. [Errors in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/error.html)
2. [Error Names in Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/error.html#error_Error-name)

**In the Nest Exception filter :**

```
import { Error } from 'mongoose';
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter} from '@nestjs/common';

@Catch(Error)
export class MongooseExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {

     constructor(//Dependencies){}

     catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {
         //exception.name will be one of the strings mentioned in the 
         //Error Names in Mongoose link
         const exceptionType = exception.name;
         //handleException...
      }
}
```

**Now to answer your question:**

> The question is, from where should I import this MongoError so that
> NestJS will catch the errors that mongoose will throw. From what I see
> neither mongoose nor @nestjs/mongoose are exposing this object.

NestJS simply wraps the `mongoose` package so that, it can be used as an importable module. It neither modifies nor work with mongodb. Thats why you still have install mongoose along with it. So there will be no mongo related error that comes from the `@nestjs/mongoose` package. As for the `MongoError`, Mongoose handles the `MongoError` and neatly presents it in its own way (refer *Errors in Mongoose* link) and throws it. I don't think there is a way to import the native `MongoError` from mongoose package or to make mongoose throw native `MongoError` instead of its own `Error`. I haven't looked into it,I'll update if there is a way.

*The above code should work. I haven't tested it. But I suggest a repository pattern where you handle all persistent store (mongodb with mongoose in this case) related exceptions in the repo layer. The context of your app is unclear to me but it is the best practice when it comes to most applications.*